# Nginx wordpress rewrites for pattern to a particular page

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to set it up so that certain URLs will rewrite (not change URL in address bar) to a particular page with identifying parameters.

I would like

```
site.com/reviews/froot_loops_review.php AND
site.com/reviews/froot_loops_review
```

to actually show

```
site.com/review?title=froot_loops
```

Additionally, I would like to be able to append any other parameters so:

```
site.com/reviews/froot_loops_review.php?var=1
```

would show what's at:

```
site.com/review?title=froot_loops&var=1
```

I'm having a hard time with this because it's my first time editing nginx conf files this is as far as I've got but it doesn't work (I think because it doesn't make the first match):

```
  location /reviews/ {
    rewrite ^/reviews/(.*)_review.php(.*) /review?title=$1 break;
    return  403;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here? What should my next step be? What is a good resource for learning Nginx rewrites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is strictly an answer. But there are multiple issues with your current solution.

This is a WordPress site, so there is already a `location ~ \.php$` block which is handling any URI that ends with `.php`. The URI `/reviews/froot_loops_review.php` will never make it to the `location /reviews/` block in your question.

You can use the `^~` modifier on the `location` directive to force `nginx` to ignore any matching regular expression location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The rewritten URI cannot be processed within the same `location` block, so `break` is the wrong suffix to use. You will have more success using `last`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

But the main problem is WordPress itself. WordPress normally uses the REQUEST_URI (which is the URI as originally presented) to identify the requested page. Which is why we can rewrite everything to `/index.php` and still get the right page.

Trying to make WordPress use your rewritten URI without an external redirect (which you say you do not want to do) is tricky. You may be better off looking for a WordPress plugin to achieve it - or try to make the pretty permalinks work the way you want.